# How to refresh cards in Outlook Actionable Messages?

Tags: outlook, office365

I'm trying to refresh a card in [Outlook Actionable Messages](https://dev.outlook.com/Actions), but the [documentation](https://dev.outlook.com/actions/reference) doesn't specify how to do this, even though the functionality is mentioned.

I've tried returning new card data in my response using both `application/json` and `application/ld+json`, but neither of those seem to work.

I've also tried returning JSON in the `CARD-ACTION-STATUS`, but that doesn't have any effect either.

Is this functionality actually available?

Comment: CARD-UPDATE-IN-BODY meant to identify whether the the API returning refreshed cards is set or not. What needs to included before sending card JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that this functionality *is* available, but a critical piece of information is missing from the documentation: You need to set the `CARD-UPDATE-IN-BODY` header with a value of `true` and it will work.

Content type on the response doesn't seem to matter, and the `CARD-ACTION-STATUS` header seems to be ignored.

Comment: CARD-UPDATE-IN-BODY meant to identify whether the the API returning refreshed cards is set or not. What needs to included before sending card JSON?